# Simultaneous use of "Expires: 0", "no-cache", "no-store", "max-age=0, must-revalidate" - what for?

Tags: http, caching

Recently I found that our web app sends the following headers:

```
    Expires: 0
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

This is how I read it:

```
    Expires: 0
```

"Hey browser, the resource you just got has already expired"

```
    Cache-Control: [..] max-age=0 [..]
```

"Actually nevermind what I just said, please do the following:"

```
    no-cache
```

"Please cache this resource. But it's already stale, so please revalidate it before using"

```
    no-store
```

"Also please do not cache anything"

```
    max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

"Also please cache this resource. But if you want to use it after 0 seconds has passed - please revalidate it."

There can be 2 explanations to this:

- The person writing it didn't know what they were doing
- They actually knew it very well. I.e. they catered to some edge-case browser behavior / bugs / something that I am missing.

What exactly they might have tried to avoid?

Bonus question 1: is my understanding correct that `Expires: 0` is (rough, with caveats) equivalent of `no-cache` rather than `no-store`? I.e. it allows caching but the caches become stale immediately - it does not prevent caching?

Bonus question 2: shouldn't I add `proxy-revalidate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching is an *optional* feature of the HTTP protocol and it's defined in the [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234). The [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) header is used to specify directives for caches along the request/response chain.

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) from Mozilla, you can use following [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) directives to turn off caching in HTTP/1.1:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

The `max-age` directive set to `0` is irrelevant when the above [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) directives are used (but it doesn't hurt).

---

One may also want to add an [`Expires`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) header set to `0` in case the recipient doesn't support `Cache-Control`. From the [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234):

> If a response includes a `Cache-Control` field with the `max-age` directive, a recipient MUST ignore the `Expires` field.  Likewise, if a response includes the `s-maxage` directive, a shared cache recipient MUST ignore the `Expires` field.  In both these cases, the value in `Expires` is only intended for recipients that have not yet implemented the `Cache-Control` field.

---

The `proxy-revalidate` directive works in the same way as `must-revalidate` but it only applies to shared caches (e.g., proxies). That is, the cache must verify the status of the stale resources before using it and expired ones should not be used.

---

I found this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) about HTTP caching from Google pretty insightful.