# Browser has cached old JQuery script and clients must force reload page after Laravel app update on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, webserver, hosting

I have a Laravel application on my hosting. After update some functions in JQuery, clients must force reload page (ctrl + shift + R) for getting new functions. It seems like browser cached old JQuery script and don't download new version of them.

How to force the browsers to force reload, when I add some new features in JQuery scripts in my Laravel app on my hosting?

Comment: You could add an argument to the script URL: `<script src="/js/my_functions.js?ver=3">`. This is for version 3, then when you update it, use `ver=4`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks. Does it work for only for .js or for other types of scripts like .css?

Comment: It will work for .css as well. When you change an URL argument the browser needs to reload the resource because the URL has changed.

Comment: That said, it MAY be cached along the way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984127/2569323 .

Comment: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/versioning This may help in more “beautiful”  way